# Is there a way to make this code 'normal'

Tags: python

i was decoding/deencrypting this code, and the python came looking like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iONS2.png)

```html
200d\\U0001f466)))|(?:(?:(?:\\U0001f468\\u200d\\U0001f468)|(?:\\U0001f469\\u200d\\U0001f469))\\u200d\\U0001f466)|[\\u2194-\\u2199]|[\\u23e9-\\u23f3]|[\\u23f8-\\u23fa]|[\\u25fb-\\u25fe]|[\\u2600-\\u2604]|[\\u2638-\\u263a]|[\\u2648-\\u2653]|[\\u2692-\\u2694]|[\\u26f0-\\u26f5]|[\\u26f7-\\u26fa]|[\\u2708-\\u270d]|[\\u2753-\\u2755]|[\\u2795-\\u2797]|[\\u2b05-\\u2b07]|[\\U0001f191-\\U0001f19a]|[\\U0001f1e6-\\U0001f1ff]|[\\U0001f232-\\U0001f23a]|[\\U0001f300-\\U0001f321]|[\\U0001f324-\\U0001f393]|[\\U0001f399-\\U0001f39b]|[\\U0001f39e-\\U0001f3f0]|[\\U0001f3f3-\\U0001f3f5]|[\\U0001f3f7-\\U0001f3fa]|[\\U0001f400-\\U0001f4fd]|[\\U0001f4ff-\\U0001f53d]|[\\U0001f549-\\U0001f54e]|[\\U0001f550-\\U0001f567]|[\\U0001f573-\\U0001f57a]|[\\U0001f58a-\\U0001f58d]|[\\U0001f5c2-\\U0001f5c4]|[\\U0001f5d1-\\U0001f5d3]|[\\U0001f5dc-\\U0001f5de]|[\\U0001f5fa-\\U0001f64f]|[\\U0001f680-\\U0001f6c5]|[\\U0001f6cb-\\U0001f6d2]|[\\U0001f6e0-\\U0001f6e5]|[\\U0001f6f3-\\U0001f6f6]|[\\U0001f910-\\U0001f91e]|[\\U0001f920-\\U0001f927]|[\\U0001f933-\\U0001f93a]|[\\U0001f93c-\\U0001f93e]|[\\U0001f940-\\U0001f945]|[\\U0001f947-\\U0001f94b]|[\\U0001f950-\\U0001f95e]|[\\U0001f980-\\U0001f991]|\\u00a9|\\u00ae|\\u203c|\\u2049|\\u2122|\\u2139|\\u21a9|\\u21aa|\\u231a|\\u231b|\\u2328|\\u23cf|\\u24c2|\\u25aa|\\u25ab|\\u25b6|\\u25c0|\\u260e|\\u2611|\\u2614|\\u2615|\\u2618|\\u261d|\\u2620|\\u2622|\\u2623|\\u2626|\\u262a|\\u262e|\\u262f|\\u2660|\\u2663|\\u2665|\\u2666|\\u2668|\\u267b|\\u267f|\\u2696|\\u2697|\\u2699|\\u269b|\\u269c|\\u26a0|\\u26a1|\\u26aa|\\u26ab|\\u26b0|\\u26b1|\\u26bd|\\u26be|\\u26c4|\\u26c5|\\u26c8|\\u26ce|\\u26cf|\\u26d1|\\u26d3|\\u26d4|\\u26e9|\\u26ea|\\u26fd|\\u2702|\\u2705|\\u270f|\\u2712|\\u2714|\\u2716|\\u271d|\\u2721|\\u2728|\\u2733|\\u2734|\\u2744|\\u2747|\\u274c|\\u274e|\\u2757|\\u2763|\\u2764|\\u27a1|\\u27b0|\\u27bf|\\u2934|\\u2935|\\u2b1b|\\u2b1c|\\u2b50|\\u2b55|\\u3030|\\u303d|\\u3297|\\u3299|\\U0001f004|\\U0001f0cf|\\U0001f170|\\U0001f171|\\U0001f17e|\\U0001f17f|\\U0001f18e|\\U0001f201|\\U0001f202|\\U0001f21a|\\U0001f22f|\\U0001f250|\\U0001f251|\\U0001f396|\\U0001f397|\\U0001f56f|\\U0001f570|\\U0001f587|\\U0001f590|\\U0001f595|\\U0001f596|\\U0001f5a4|\\U0001f5a5|\\U0001f5a8|\\U0001f5b1|\\U0001f5b2|\\U0001f5bc|\\U0001f5e1|\\U0001f5e3|\\U0001f5e8|\\U0001f5ef|\\U0001f5f3|\\U0001f6e9|\\U0001f6eb|\\U0001f6ec|\\U0001f6f0|\\U0001f930|\\U0001f9c0|[#|0-9]\\u20e3"\r\n\r\n\r\n@Exeter.command(aliases=["stopcopycatuser", "stopcopyuser", "stopcopy"])\r\nasync def stopcopycat(ctx):\r\n    await ctx.message.delete()\r\n    if Exeter.user is None:\r\n        await ctx.send("You weren\'t copying anyone to begin with")\r\n        return\r\n    await ctx.send("Stopped copying " + str(Exeter.copycat))\r\n    Exeter.copycat = None\r\n\r\n\r\n@Exeter.command(aliases=["copycatuser", "copyuser"])\r\nasync def copycat(ctx, user: discord.User):\r\n    await ctx.message.delete()\r\n    Exeter.copycat = user\r\n    await ctx.send("Now copying " + str(Exet
```

Is there anyway to turn this into normal python code? Below are the encrypted/ecoded file and the decrypted/decoded file.

[Encoded File (Filebin)](https://filebin.net/y8l6jabvz2bjp4p6/encoded.py?t=awl25sh9)

[Decoded File (Filebin)](https://filebin.net/armnkl8vo5xie3xp)

Comment: is the encoded file supposed to be run ? I'm not seeing any exec there

Comment: i think i've uploaded the wrong file but yes. let me reupload the file.

Comment: @painor thanks for pointing that out. i've uploaded the right file.

Comment: Can you post a smaller sample within your question, which isn't in image format?

Comment: sure, @MateenUlhaq

Comment: I was able to decode the file successfully. looks like you just made a mistake somewhere while trying to decode it. it's just a simple b64 encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but most of your file seems to look correct when it is un-escaped and printed out. For example, simply copy-pasting from your `decoded.txt` file into a python REPL and printing it out produces:

```
>>> print(
... """\r\n@Exeter.command(aliases=["stopcopycatuser", "stopcopyuser", "stopc
... opy"])\r\nasync def stopcopycat(ctx):\r\n    await ctx.message.delete()\r
... \n    if Exeter.user is None:\r\n        await ctx.send("You weren\'t cop
... ying anyone to begin with")\r\n        return\r\n    await ctx.send("Stop
... ped copying " + str(Exeter.copycat))\r\n    Exeter.copycat = None\r\n"""
... )

@Exeter.command(aliases=["stopcopycatuser", "stopcopyuser", "stopcopy"])
async def stopcopycat(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    if Exeter.user is None:
        await ctx.send("You weren't copying anyone to begin with")
        return
    await ctx.send("Stopped copying " + str(Exeter.copycat))
    Exeter.copycat = None
```

One way to accomplish this programmatically with your `decoded.txt` is:

```
with read("decoded.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()

unescaped = data.encode("utf8").decode("unicode_escape")
print(unescaped)
```

Answer (score 3):

The code is simply using b64 encoding. to decode it you can just print the result that is passed to eval

```
data = ((base64.b64decode(eval('\x74\x72\x75\x73\x74')),'<string>','exec'))
print(data[0].decode("utf-8"))
```

if you want to avoid evals you can use

```
joy = 'rot13'

trust = magic + codecs.decode(love, joy) + god + codecs.decode(destiny, joy)

code = (base64.b64decode(trust),'<string>','exec')
print(code[0].decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: `eval('\x74\x72\x75\x73\x74')` is equivalent to the variable name `trust`, so OP could also replace that to avoid the `eval`.